# Recording - Unwanted Vibration / Rumble

Tags: audio-recording, noise, troubleshooting

Using a Sennheiser MKH50 (high-pass filter on) to a Millennia HV-35P preamp (gain 85%), I sometimes get unwanted sounds in the form of vibrations / rumbles. Example below in a 4 second clip that has the vibration at 2 seconds.

The mic is 1.7 meters from the source of sound: Rain on a window.

It is mounted in a Rycote InVision 7HG MKIII Microphone Shock Mount on a mic stand.

Can anyone identify what this sound is and the mistake I'm making that is causing it?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could be the window vibrating for some reason. What’s the corner frequency of the high pass filter? Do you have a shock mount for the mic?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I have updated my question to mention the shock mount and here are the details regarding the high pass filter: 12dB / oct below 30 Hz. I have had this sound occur when I'm pointing the mic at other sources.

Comment: Maybe more examples would help. Also a 30 Hz high pass will not cut out most rumble. 80hz would be a better corner frequency for that. If you take any step across the floor or if someone in the same building closes a door it could cause that sound. How controlled is the environment?

Comment: Not controlled at all. In normal circumstances, a quiet apartment. I suspect it was a distant vehicle. It can be removed using Izotope. It just surprised me as I couldn't (and can't) identify its origin. It seemed to appear out of nowhere.